# How much time has passed since the last time it was "X" a clock

Tags: java, time

I'm wondering how to find how much time has passed since the last time it was 8:45 in Java.

ex.
time: 8:44  -> 23:59 
time  8:46  -> 00.01

I have a rather ugly solution now.

```
if (calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) >= 8) {
    if (calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) >= 45 || calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) > 9) {
        System.out.println("it between 8:45 and 00:00");
    }
}
else {
    System.out.println("its between 00:00 and 8:45");
}
```

Comment: Easier with Period(available on java 1.8) - [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html)

Comment: Are we talking straight 24-hour days?  Or do you need to consider the missing time gaps and repeated time overlaps created by [daylight saving time](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info) transitions?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
public void test() {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar eightFortyFive = Calendar.getInstance();
    eightFortyFive.set(Calendar.HOUR, 8);
    eightFortyFive.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 45);
    eightFortyFive.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    eightFortyFive.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    // You might not need to do this or you may need to use -24.
    if (eightFortyFive.after(c)) {
        eightFortyFive.add(Calendar.HOUR, -12);
    }
    System.out.println("Time since " + eightFortyFive.getTime() + " = " + new Date(c.getTimeInMillis() - eightFortyFive.getTimeInMillis()));

}
```

Essentially you must take the current time, set hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds to what you want and subtract 12 or 24 hours if necessary. You can then create a new `Date` which is the difference between the two.

Comment: You'll want to subtract 24 hours - it's pretty clear from the OP that he's dealing with a 24-hour clock.

Comment: @dcsohl - I'm not certain I actually need the subtract.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get to the days between dates you can use something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long initial = getTime("20-jul-2015 11:09:25"); /*you use System.currentTimeMillis() at the beginning*/
    long finalTime = getTime("21-jul-2016 15:21:26"); /*you use System.currentTimeMillis() at the capture of final time.*/
    printElapsedTime(initial, finalTime);
  }

  private static void printElapsedTime(long initial, long finalTime) {
    long lapse = finalTime - initial; 
    long secs = (lapse/(1000))%60;
    long mins = lapse/(1000*60)%60;
    long hrs = lapse/(1000*60*60)%24;
    long days = lapse/(1000*60*60*24);

    StringBuilder lapseMsg = new StringBuilder("Elapsed time since ").append(new Date(initial)).append(" to " + new Date(finalTime)).append(":\r\n");
    lapseMsg.append(days).append(" Days, ").append(hrs).append(" Hours, ").append(mins).append(" Minutes, ").append(secs).append(" seconds");
    System.out.println(lapseMsg.toString());
  }

  /*just used to get any date to test.*/
  private static long getTime(String date) {
    DateFormat format = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
    try {
      return format.parse(date).getTime();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException();
    }
  }
```

if you need something more complex like get the lapsed Months you may use Calendar, making some fixes to the @OldCurmudgeon solution. (It didn't work for me the way it is)